# Does Variance Reduction really help the Nonparametric Test?

Tags: variance, statistical-power, permutation-test

In Online Experiment, Working on Variance Reductions could help a lot for the traditional parametric tests like test two-proportion (CTR) or two-mean t-test, as it significantly improves the power and limits the number of samples needed for the experiment.

On the other side, does it really help with non-parametric tests? for example permutation test two percentiles. As for non-parametric, we don't make any assumption for the underlying distribution and it is usually hard to analyze the power analytically. So is the variance-reduction still meaningful in this case?

Comment: I think I know, but what do you mean when you say "variance"?

Comment: I mean the sample variance.

Comment: Does reducing sample variance improve the power of a t-test?

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to remember that the variance of your data reflects a) differences due to factors you care about and can measure (*signal*), and b) differences due to factors you don't care about of can't measure (*noise*): $\sigma^2_{\text{Total}} = \sigma^2_{\text{Signal}} + \sigma^2_{\text{Noise}}$. The power of any test, parametric or non-parametric, depends on the signal-to-noise ratio, $\frac{\sigma^2_{\text{Signal}}}{\sigma^2_{\text{Noise}}}$.

In general, reducing the variance of your sample isn't useful, because it involves reducing both the signal and the noise. **Anything that reduces only the noise variance** (for example, by obtaining more precise measurements) **is always useful no matter what test you use**.